# Parsing tokens into char ** with user input fgets()

Tags: arrays, c, tokenize, fgets

My problem is quite similar to the problem here: [Trimming a trailing \0 from fgets() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318651/trimming-a-trailing-0-from-fgets-in-c)
However, the suggested solution `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;` as I am using char ** to store the tokens

Here's my code:

```
char str[1024];
fgets(str, 1024, stdin);

const char s[2] = " ";
char *token;
char ** token_arr = malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));
int pos = 0;

token = strtok(str, s);

while( token != NULL) {
  token_arr[pos] = token;
  printf( "%d %s\n", pos, token );
  pos++;
  token = strtok(NULL, s);
}

int i = 0;
while (token_arr[i]) {
printf("%d %s \n", i, token_arr[i]);
i++;
}
```

Input:
`a b c d e`

The printf in each loop is separated by a blank line, which I presume is due to the trailing \0 that is perhaps stored inside the token_arr.
How can I remove it?

Thanks a lot

ETA: What I meant it each print loop is printing an unintended extra blank line.

Comment: *Every* string has a trailing `'\0'`. The OP of the linked question is confused. You both might have meant a trailing `'\n'`. The suggested answer is correct. Do that before splitting the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to gets(), fgets() keeps the newline that you typed in after your input.

Since the newline is not in your list of tokens it is kept as a part of the last token, hence the empty line.

just replace `const char s[2] = " ";`
with
`const char s[3] = " \n";`

Comment: Note `strtok` will happily output empty tokens.